# Picklist value Control visibility of records

Tags: picklist, profile, object, custom-profile

I have to remove visibility of a profile to records of my custom object which are having Status__c picklist value as 'A'. Can someone suggest a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new record type for when Status__c is equal to 'A'. You can then remove visibility for the record to users with the profile you don't want to see it while allowing it for other users that you want to continue allowing read or read/write access to the record.